# Jenkins jobs are running forever

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am new to jenkins, I have installed jenkins manually on EC2 instance, however when I do gradle clean install command, the jobs are running forever, earlier it used to show java heap out of memory issues but after tweaking values in GRADLE_OPTS & jenkins file, I see jobs never end. Please help in decode this? I am completely blocked.

**jenkins file has below:**
[image]

**Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Configure System**
[image]

Also has this question which will override jenkins file or values in Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > GRADLE_OPTS ?

**EC2 has below memory:**
[image]

**jenkins monitor(Java Melody) plugin showed below stats:**
[image]

Comment: can you confirm you are experiencing this infinite loop when test-cases are running?

Comment: @surajs1n I don't think there is issue with test case, because these are running fine locally and also on devops pipeline. While building it self I see it's stuck forever at this step:      > Task :project1:compileJava 
Note: Processing Log4j annotations
Note: Annotations processed ...